# Retry same findElement statement after handling unexpected popup

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, ui-automation

In my application, there is ab unexpected popup that shows up on any screen which makes the test case fail. I can surround `findelement` with try-catch for most likely places but it may happen on any screen so this is not a good idea to cover every `findelement` statement with try-catch.

I would like to have a mechanism if `findelement` fails at any place due to an unexpected pop up. The mechanism should handle the pop up and retry the same find element statement one more time and return back to test execution to continue future steps.

After doing some research on Internet, I feel it can be done using `WebDriverEventListener` and tried but it didn't work.

Can someone please provide a solution or suggestion how this can be achieved?

I am using Java Selenium TestNG in Framework

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If the pop-up can appear at anytime, you will need to modify methods like sendkeys etc etc. Seems like a bad option. Rather ask the developers to shut off the pop-ups for testing. Must be a kill switch..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread your posts and take a look here to learn how to format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TestNG Create a pop handling/closing method and put the same into @BeforeMethod annotation of TestNG , to get this done